# Ubuntu 12.04.3 Server i386 fail to install kernel

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, package-management

I've been trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS i386 from a CD-ROM on a Pentium IV 3GHz machine, always with the same problem - it doesn't manage to install linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic.
I checked the MD5 Check Sum of the ISO file and it is OK. I checked the integrity of the CD-ROM and it is also OK.
The error reported from syslog is transcript below (it is impossible to copy it from the console by this time):

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/media/cdrom/pool/main/l/linux-lts-raring/linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic_3.8.0-29.42~precise1_i386.deb
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Reading pagckage lists...
Building dependency tree...
linux-headers-generic-lts-raring is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-generic-lts-raring: Depends: linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic but it is not going to be installed
Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

The suggested solution of `apt-get -f install` was innocuous, as the system couldn't find 'apt-get'. It also couldn't find dpkg.

I have previously installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop in this same machine with no problems at all. Now I would like very much to run the Server version, as all I want to do is build a small server.
What can I do to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

It was my mistake :( After having tried everything else, I decided to start all over, repartitionning the disk and so on. When repartionning the disk I found that the partition "/boot" had been asigned only 1 MB, instead of 1 GB, as planned. Obviously there wasn't enough space to put the system there. Just brought it up to 1 GB and, voilà! Problem solved.
Anyway, the installer could very well have detected this and signaled the lack of space! It would have been much simpler.